# Unwanted periodic request in express in amazon Ec2

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

I am having this strange issue. I am running a `node.js`, `express.js` server in Amazon EC2 instance. But when I see my logs there is this log which is originated from my own domain (Elastic IP) (req.ip ::ffff:xxx.174.27.39) and its happening every second. Even if I am idle and not calling the API.

```
GET /json 404 0.619 ms - 143
GET /json/version 404 1.939 ms - 151
```

Any idea ? What else I need to share to get help? Sorry I am not a Dev Ops so do not have any good knowledge.

Comment: Show us some code. Would be hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: I am having this same issue -- did you ever figure out what was causing this?